# Local Jekyll doesn't generate proper RSS feed

Tags: github, rss, markdown, jekyll, liquid

I use Jekyll with Github Pages. I don't use the Jekyll-Feed plugin because I want to build a specific feed with my own configuration. 
The feed on Github Pages works perfectly fine and generates the content the way it should. But when I want to do this locally the feed content is in Markdown instead of the generated HTML.
The code for the feed is found on https://github.com/frankmeeuwsen/DTD-Blog/blob/master/feed.xml

How can this happen? Is there a change in how Jekyll builds the site locally and remote? Is there something else I should look at? Any help pointing in a direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Jekyll builds a local site and a remote site *almost identically*, there may be differences between how GitHub Pages build a site and how Jekyll builds a site if there are version discrepancies.

GitHub Pages uses **only the versions listed in https://pages.github.com/versions/**

So, to ensure you have the same "bundle of gems" locally and at remote, use `github-pages` gem in your Gemfile:

```
gem "github-pages"
```

*Note: You'll not be able to use plugins not listed in the link above, when building with the `github-pages` gem*

Comment: That's what helped me! I commented the other gems in my Gemfile and just installed the github-pages one. this gives me the exact same situation as remote. Thanks a lot!